# Magento: What is the reference name for the block controlled by attributes.phtml? (using EasyTabs)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm using Magento with the EasyTabs extension. I have a customized attributes.phtml I want to use for certain products, I'm trying to use a design update XML to switch the default attributes.phtml for the custom one on certain products only. I'm trying to figure out the correct reference name for that block.

The template hint for the block shows:

```
frontend/default/MY_THEME_NAME/template/easytabs/attributes.phtml
```

The XML I'm trying to use for the layout update is:

```
<reference name="[REFERENCE NAME???]">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>[CUSTOM ATTRIBUTES.PHTML]</template></action>
</reference>
```

I've tried:

```
product.info.attributes 
product_info_attributes 
product.attributes 
product_attributes
easytabs.attributes
easytabs_attributes
product.view.attributes
product_view_attributes
```

None of these are working. What is the correct reference name for this block when using EasyTabs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what "EasyTabs" are, but if you temporarily edit `attributes.phtml` to include the following

```
<?php var_dump($this->getNameInLayout()); ?>
```

the name of the block will be output to the screen.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it for me - just output it into an HTML comment. For the record, the block name was "additional_tabbed". Surprised Magento doesn't provide an easier way to discover these names. This code will help a lot though. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Happy to help.  FWIW, the graphviz feature of my commercial debugging extension allows you to zero in on this stuff rather easily.  http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/  The way Magento itself would want you to do this is find the layout update xml file (or php observer file) `attributes.phtml` was added in and identify the name from that code.

Comment: Well I did look in catalog.xml where attributes.phtml is listed with a block name of "product.attributes" which was one that I tried without success. I believe the EasyTabs extension may have overridden that entry with its own name for the block which was why I mentioned EasyTabs in my question. I will check out your debugging extension. Thanks again!

Comment: Also wondering why the "Add Block Names to Hints" feature in the admin doesn't show the same name. That would make it so easy, but the name I get for this block when using that feature is "Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes" rather than "additional_tabbed".. wonder if I could edit some Magento core file to replace however they get the block names with getNameInLayout()...

Comment: <?php var_dump($this->getNameInLayout()); ?> GREAT AND EASY TO USE TIP